# get php posted id on ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I added two buttons, 1 on html and one on php .... 
by getting second button with ajax..

but when i add event to the buttons the one on the html page works only ... need some help....

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="button 1" class="btn">
 <div id="div"><div>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url:"btn2.php", success:function(data){
  $('#div').html(data);}
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
    alert("button is wrking");
});

</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

echo"<input type='button' value='button 2' class='btn'>";
?>
```

can any one help me on this

Comment: You can't use HTML inside PHP like that. I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Could you explain?

Comment: I guess this will solve your problem: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: use `echo '<input type="button" value="button 2" class="btn">'; ` on your PHP code.

Comment: @Gerep `.live()` is deprecated. See my answer or the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code results in a syntax error. Output it as a string:

```
<?php
  echo '<input type="button" value="button 2" class="btn">';
?>
```

The PHP aren't even needed:

```
<input type="button" value="button 2" class="btn">
```

Another problem is that your jQuery code doesn't work because it selects the element which are present at the time of the function call, but your button will be loaded (asynchronically) afterwards!

```
$( "#div" ).on( "click", ".btn", function() {
  alert("button1 is working");
});
```

Comment: @DisHonest You're welcome. For delegated events (these which also affect later added elements), you have to first select an element which is present at the current time (`#div` in your case), then you have to specify the actual selector in the second parameter (`.btn`). (Please do not forget to mark [an answer as the accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).)

Comment: @DisHonest You use the `live()` method in the wrong way! It's deprecated anyway, why do you want to use it?

Comment: I want the value of btn id without clicking it from div table

Comment: originally i have assigned an hidden value in div ... returned from php .... now i want to access the value of hidden field which is in div... ..

Comment: @DisHonest I do not fully understand your comments. Could you please post a new question?

Answer (score 0):

pls dont enclose the html code within `<?PHP ?>` tags

if you put simply

```
<input type="button" value="button 2" class="btn">
```

in your ajax target page(btn2.php) it would work.

### update

To get the already defined `click handler` working for the ajax loaded content also
use

```
$('.btn').live('click', function({ alert(1); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your click event in ajax response Or use `.on()` as @ComFreek suggested

```
$.ajax({
  url:"btn2.php", 
success:function(data){
  $('#div').html(data);
$('.btn').click(function(){
    alert("button1 is wrking");
}); 
}
});
```